# How can PE system recognize smart phone WinPE?

Tags: windows-10, mtp

I can not make Windows PE x64 to recognize smart phones. I try to install drivers but it says "...find drivers but encounter a probelem..." Any idea?

Comment: Are the smartphones configured to transfer data (MTP)? Have you tried another cable? Did you make sure that the cable you're using is not charge-only?

Comment: Which smart phones have you tried?

Comment: I doubt this is possible in WinPE, as the purpose of WinPE [**Win**dows **P**reinstallation **E**nvironment] is only meant to be used to either install Windows or as a recovery environment for Windows _(WinRE [**R**ecovery **E**nvironment], which includes two additional WinPE OCs vital to recovering Windows)_].  Additionally, **it's extremely unwise to connect an insecure device, such as a smartphone, while within WinPE/WinRE**, as it would allow any malware on the smartphone to potentially exploit the PC _(WinPE has no firewall or antivirus)_.

Comment: Yes it is configured to MTP
Yes I try another cable.
The cable is not charge only, I use this cable in normal Windows 10, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Windows PE is not a full Windows environment and as such lacks a lot of drivers and support for alternative access methods (apparently) such as MTP.

From https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro

> Windows PE is not a general-purpose operating system. It may not be used for any purpose other than deployment and recovery. It should not be used as a thin client or an embedded operating system. There are other Microsoft products, such as Windows Embedded CE, which may be used for these purposes.

If you need these features then install a full operating system or use a Linux LiveDVD. If you are trying to transfer files from a phone then you may have to use an intermediate computer to download the files and transfer them to a normal USB stick.

Comment: Say I'm a technician... Say I use PE for recovery and I need a program which accidentally stored in my smartphone.. Do I give up?
I made my own PE and want to add smart phone support feature. I just want to know how can I do it?

Comment: If you were a technician you would value your time better and get one of those USB sticks that you can connect to your [smartphone and a computer for £10](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=usb+memory+stick+dual). That would save you time in future and days of hassle trying to "fix" a problem that you made for yourself. WinPE is a minimal operating system and lacks a lot of the features of its parent. Some problems aren't worth the effort of fixing when better/faster/easier solutions are available. [Pounding A Nail: Old Shoe or Glass Bottle?](https://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/408925)

Comment: Thanks for your advices. Be sure that I know all this stuff. I was just wondering if there is a way or not.

Comment: Microsoft intentionally pared back a major distribution of their operating system to the bare essentials necessary to do disk maintenance and setup. They do not provide installers for individual modules such as MTP and these things generally have settings, libraries and executables spread across a wide area. Comparing the differences between Windows and WinPE would be a difficult job at the best of times and trying to pick out which bits to put back for one feature would be a painstaking task needing time with both. If it doesn't just work then you have a lot of reverse engineering to do.